# how to identify if raid1 or raid mirror configure on OS disk

Tags: linux, raid, disk, dmesg, raid1

we want to verify if raid1 is configured on out linux machine 
so we found the answer on - https://serverfault.com/questions/110843/how-to-determine-if-a-centos-system-is-raid-1

but from the output -  how we can be sure that raid1 is configured?

and how to understand it from the command: **dmesg | grep raid**

when non raid , and when raid1 is configured ?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [linux + tool that can identify RAID configuration](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409945/linux-tool-that-can-identify-raid-configuration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output in the image you attached isn't necessarily showing you what you think it is. The "megaraid_sas" bits aren't specifying any RAID level in the OS, they're specifying the use of the "megaraid_sas" driver to access the disk. Given that, you are very likely using a MegaRAID controller, which is capable of various RAID levels, but to see the configuration you would need to be in the MegaRAID BIOS screen. That information usually isn't available from the OS. When configured for RAID-1, the MegaRAID card will hide the two physical disks from the system, and will present the kernel and OS with only a single disk device.

In short: check your MegaRAID BIOS configuration.

Comment: MegaRAID BIOS configuration.  is relevant for each HW? ( because some server are dell and some others etc )

Comment: This answer is only relevant for systems which have and use a MegaRAID controller card. Other systems with other RAID controllers will have a different driver in use and a different BIOS to check.