# linux + tool that can identify RAID configuration

Tags: linux, raid, disk, raid1, raid0

I am searching for a long time tool that can runs as CLI on linux machine
and identify which RAID configuration is defined on the disk or disks ( according to the list from lsblk )

the reason for that we cant showdown ( Production machines ) the linux machine and look on the RAID controler when OS id down

I am just cant understand why it is so difficult to capture the RAID conf when OS is up , must be somewhere tool that identify the RAID configuration

Comment: You already asked this question. I answered it. There is no tool that will tell you the firmware RAID controller's configuration all the time.

Comment: You may read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163) to tune your English with only a little work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the make and model of your hardware?

At least some Fujitsu PRIMERGY servers use the `megaraid_sas` kernel module for their RAID controller. And Fujitsu provides a tool called ServerView RAID Manager which includes a command-line tool and a web GUI, both of which can both view and modify the RAID configuration. I think `amCLI` was the name of their command-line tool.

Dell has a `MegaCli` command-line tool for their LSI MegaRAID controllers.

You should check your hardware vendor's support pages for your specific OS + hardware model combination, and see if they offer any useful downloadables.

Comment: we have HP servers , do you know the tool that fit for HP?

Comment: I found this - https://access.redhat.com/discussions/536883

Comment: Yes, HP (now HPe) has a similar (but not identical) tool for the purpose, named `hpacucli`. Looks like a lot of their downloads require a valid warranty or support registration now, so I cannot give you a direct link.